# unix date format converting HKT or JST to EST timezone

Tags: date, unix

While converting the date to +%-m/%-d/%Y using date format in unix, I'm getting dates converted to timezones. HKT or JST timezones to EST, I want the date as is to be converted as mm/dd/yy without this timezone conversion

Example:

```
$ date -u '--d=Sun Jan 25 08:39:12 JST 2015' +%-m/%-d/%Y
1/24/2015
```

I also tried with -u -d options

```
$ date -u -d 'Sun Jan 25 08:39:12 JST 2015' +%-m/%-d/%Y
1/24/2015
```

Can someone please help me with the solution.

Comment: why do you use `-u` that prints time in UTC?

Answer (score 0):

To change the output timezone, you could set `TZ` envvar:

```
$ TZ=EST date -d 'Sun Jan 25 08:39:12 JST 2015' 
Sat Jan 24 18:39:12 EST 2015
$ TZ=JST date -d 'Sun Jan 25 08:39:12 JST 2015' 
Sun Jan 25 08:39:12 JST 2015
```

To ignore the input timezone or to detect it automatically, a Python script could be used:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Change date/time format.

Usage: $ {prog} <input-date-time> <output-format>

Example: $ ./change-date-format 'Sun Jan 25 08:39:12 JST 2015' %-m/%-d/%Y
Output:  1/25/2015
"""
import sys
from dateutil.parser import parse # apt-get install python-dateutil
try:
    date_string, date_format = sys.argv[1:]
except ValueError:
    sys.exit(__doc__.format(prog=sys.argv[0])) # print usage info
else:
    datetime_object = parse(date_string)
    print(datetime_object.strftime(date_format))
```